# orrosplanning test failure

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

I downloaded openrave_planning stack and try to run the test file.

```
rosrun orrosplanning ik_openrave.py
```

Got the following error:

```
import orrosplanning.srv 


ImportError: No module named orrosplanning.srv`
```

Seems orrosplanning.srv is missing. Thanks for any suggestions.

ps: I didn't find orrosplanning.srv in /home/fei/openrave_planning/orrosplanning/srv, so do I miss some file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10385/orrosplanning-test-failure/) by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haibin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18818/haibin/) on 2014-06-08**:
Hi Fei Liu,

I am studying orrosplanning. But when I rosmake it and met the following errors at "xmlreaders-core.cpp", at line 98 in openrave package: no member DEBUGGING at Assimp:Logger... But I have installed the newest version of Assimp-dev 3.0. Could you help me about that?

Many thanks,
Haibin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you made everything inside openrave_planning?

```
roscd openrave_planning
rosmake
```

---

Originally posted by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) with karma: 152 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on 2011-06-23**:
you are welcome! openrave updates very often, so every time after I update, i rosmake everything again.

**Comment by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on 2011-06-23**:
Thanks for your suggestion and time. I just re-rosmake it and it works. It is amazing, but I did rosmake it before I use it.

**Comment by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on 2011-06-23**:
hmm... i don't have that file either, but i could run rosrun orrosplanning ik_openrave.py without any problem... and your PYTHONPATH is NOT the same as mine, are you sure you included openrave's python libraries?

**Comment by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on 2011-06-23**:
Yes, I have rosmake it. Could you check if you have the orrosplanning.srv under ../openrave_planning/orrosplanning/srv? I doubt I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the problem is that orrosplanning is not compiled:

```
rosmake openrave_planning
```

It has nothing to do with including the openrave python library inside PYTHONPATH

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1